# Process ZipArchive entries in parallel

Tags: .net, multithreading, zip, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I need to process [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) entries as strings. Currently I have code like this:

```c#
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileName))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
        {
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // doing something with s
        }
    }
}
```

The processing could be much faster if it was done on several CPU cores in parallel using [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) or a similar loop. The problem is that `ZipArchive` is not thread-safe.

Perhaps, we could use the [Partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner) class to get ranges from [ZipArchive.Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries) to feed them into a `Parallel.ForEach` loop and then open the zip archive again and every entry in the loop body using a new instance of `ZipArchive` to be thread-safe, but I have no good idea how to do that. Is it possible?

If not, is there another reliable way to process zip archive entries in parallel if we just need to read them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumption is right, the multi-threaded version of my code processing a ZipArchive should look like this:

```c#
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileName))
{
    var ranges = Partitioner.Create(0, archive.Entries.Count);
    
    Parallel.ForEach(ranges, range =>
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive2 = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileName))
            for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive2.Entries[i];
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                {
                    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    // doing something with s
                }
            }
    }
}
```

P.S. Just for general information. My time measurements show that this version of code works 25%-40% slower compared to the original one-threaded code. So that's a question whether we should process a zip archive from multiple threads. Don't forget to measure performance of multi-threaded code for your archives to be sure that this approach helps to boost performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just have each thread create its own `ZipArchive` and `ZipArchiveEntry` objects. It takes very little time to step through the central directory, so give each thread its own number *n* for which entry to process, and then a given thread will step through the entries *n* times to get to its entry. There should be no problem having multiple `ZipArchive` objects reading the same zip file.

Comment: An idea expressed in words is good, but at Stackoverflow I expected to see a code solution. Can we use the fact that `ZipArchive.Entries` return the same collection of archive entries for different `ZipArchive` objects in different threads (same items, same order)?

Comment: If you're asking if the order of the entries returned by `Entries` is random somehow, then no, certainly not. They are in the order they appear in the central directory.

Comment: I've wrote my version of Parallel.ForEach-based processing for zip archives. See my answer. Is it what you meant?